# Does the range-based 'for' loop deprecate many simple algorithms?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++11, foreach

Algorithm solution:

```
std::generate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), rand);
```

Range-based for-loop solution:

```
for (int& x : numbers) x = rand();
```

Why would I want to use the more verbose `std::generate` over range-based for-loops in C++11?

Comment: Composability? Oh never mind, algorithms with iterators are often not composable anyway... :(

Comment: What if you've got only a pair of iterators?

Comment: ...which aren't `begin()` and `end()`?

Comment: @jrok I expect many people to have a `range` function in their toolbox by now. (i.e. `for(auto& x : range(first, last))`)

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes I'm surprised that you said "algorithms with iterators are often not composable"... I thought that was strong advantage of iterators. Can you post a link to some discussion of that? I'd like to read more. What do you have in mind that is more composable? List comprehensions?

Comment: `boost::generate(numbers, rand); // ♪`

Comment: @JamesBrock We have discussed this often in the C++ chat room (it should be somewhere in the transcripts :P). The main issue is that algorithms often return *one* iterator, and take *two* iterators.

Comment: Oh yeah that. Dietmar Kuhl is working on an std lib where algorithims always return a range.

Comment: @JamesBrock: LOL... I was wondering how *that* noteable is doing these days. (Have been sharing an office with him for some time.) This sounds just like him, tinkering. ;-)

Comment: @JamesBrock: There are three main articles dealing with iterators and possible improvements, from boost, Alexandrescu and Dietmar Kühl (I am not sure whether Dietmar's has been *officially* published). Each one of them has what could look at small differences that are not really that small. IIRC, Dietmar did not always yield a range, but did so depending on how the algorithm was called (and the returned range was also different, when you `find`, do you want the result to be `[begin(),find(...)]` or `[find(...),end()]`?). Alexandrescu proposes only ranges in a less flexible way.

Comment: @JamesBrock: the fact that `std::transform` and `boost:transform_iterator` are necessarily different code entities, is basically another way of saying that algorithms don't compose. If they did compose then you wouldn't need `transform_iterator`, you'd just compose `transform` with whatever algorithm it is that you're passing `transform_iterator`s into. Of course there are still plenty of situations where you pass the output of one algorithm into another, they just don't compose in general.

Comment: @Steve: I don't think the *lazy* algorithm iterators from Boost are good example here, since the two do different things.

Comment: @Xeo: well, we haven't had an opportunity to express whether we'd want to compose `transform` with another algorithm (for the sake of example, another transform) lazily or non-lazily, i.e. apply both transforms to each element in turn vs. apply one transform to the whole range and then the second to the results. More to the point we can't do it at all.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The Alexandrescu ranges have been sucessfully used to build a superset of the STL algorithms in the D programming language. I don't know if the other ranges have been used and tested so extensively. You could call D ranges less flexible than a pair of iterators, but they are simply at another abstraction level. Instead of  operator*, operator++ and comparison to end() they provide front(), popFront() and empty().

Comment: @rhalbersma: Yes, they are at a different abstraction level, and they are more limited than other approaches (including Dietmar's), where the user has greater control over what the resulting range is again the motivating example is the `find` algorithm, what do the user want when they `find`? The element, the range `[begin,element)`, the range `[element,end)`? I admit that I don't know how D treats this particular case, but in the article I read you could only get `[element,end)` as iterating over the range *consumes* the elements.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas In D they return `[element, end)`, I believe so that you can keep searching for Input Ranges (equivalent for Input iterators).

Comment: @rhalbersma: right, that is what I understood from Alexandrescu's article, and my comment above just meant to mention that there are other approaches that are more flexible while still allowing for componsition (i.e. obtaining the best of both worlds)

Comment: Does the presence of a function called `sort` in the standard library of your language deprecate sorting algorithms?

Comment: If both versions can be comfortably written as a single line of code, I'm doubtful you'll ever be able to name a clear winner.  The only advantage I can see to std::generate() is that it requires less modification if you later need to change to a range smaller than the full collection.  That said, repetitive typing of begin()/end() is mind-numbing after a while.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The first version

```
std::generate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), rand);
```

tells us that you want to generate a sequence of values.

In the second version the reader will have to figure that out himself.

Saving on typing is usually suboptimal, as it is most often lost in reading time. Most code is read a lot more than it is typed.

Comment: Saving on typing? Oh, I get it. Why oh why do we have the same term for "compile-time sanity checks" and "hitting keys on a keyboard"? :)

Comment: "*Saving on typing is usually suboptimal*" Nonsense; it's all about what library you're using. std::generate is long because you have to specify `numbers` twice for no reason. Hence: `boost::range::generate(numbers, rand);`. There's no reason you can't have both shorter and more legible code in a well-built library.

Comment: It's all in the eye of reader. For loop version is understandable with most programming backgrounds: put rand value to each element of collection. Std::generate requires knowing recent C++, or guessing that generate actually means "modify items", not "return generated values".

Comment: If you only want to modify part of a container then you can `std::generate(number.begin(), numbers.begin()+3, rand)`, isn't it? So  I guess to specify `number` twice may be useful sometimes.

Comment: @MarsonMao: if you only have a two-argument `std::generate()`, you can instead do `std::generate(slice(number.begin(), 3), rand)` or even better with a hypothetical range slicing syntax like `std::generate(number[0:3], rand)` which removes the repetition of `number` while still allowing flexible specification of part of the range. Doing the reverse starting from a three argument `std::generate()` is more tedious.

Comment: @hyde Exactly. I did not know what the code did until I read the for loop version.

Answer (score 42):

Whether the for loop is range based or not does not make a difference at all, it only simplifies the code inside the parenthesis. Algorithms are clearer in that they show the *intent*.

Answer (score 30):

Personally, my initial reading of:

```
std::generate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), rand);
```

is "we're assigning to everything in a range. The range is `numbers`. The values assigned are random".

My initial reading of:

```
for (int& x : numbers) x = rand();
```

is "we're doing something to everything in a range. The range is `numbers`. What we do is assign a random value."

Those are pretty darn similar, but not identical. One plausible reason I might want to provoke the first reading, is because I think the most important fact about this code is that it assigns to the range. So there's your "why would I want to...". I use `generate` because in C++ `std::generate` means "range assignment". As btw does `std::copy`, the difference between the two is what you're assigning from.

There are confounding factors, though. Range-based for loops have an inherently more direct way of expressing that the range is `numbers`, than iterator-based algorithms do. That's why people work on range-based algorithm libraries: `boost::range::generate(numbers, rand);` looks better than the `std::generate` version.

As against that, `int&` in your range-based for loop is a wrinkle. What if the value type of the range isn't `int`, then we're doing something annoyingly subtle here that depends on it being convertible to `int&`, whereas the `generate` code only depends on the return from `rand` being assignable to the element. Even if the value type is `int`, I still might stop to think about whether it is or not. Hence `auto`, which defers thinking about the types until I see what gets assigned -- with `auto &x` I say "take a reference to the range element, whatever type that might have". Back in C++03, algorithms (because they're function templates) were *the* way to hide exact types, now they're *a* way.

I think it has always been the case that the simplest algorithms have only a marginal benefit over the equivalent loops. Range-based for loops improve loops (primarily by removing most of the boilerplate, although there's a little more to them than that). So the margins draw tighter and perhaps you change your mind in some specific cases. But there's a still a style difference there.

Comment: Have you ever seen a user-defined type with an `operator int&()`? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow replace `int&` with `SomeClass&` and now you have to worry about conversion operators and single-parameter constructors not marked `explicit`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: don't think so. Which is why if it ever does happen, I won't be expecting it and no matter how paranoid I am about it now, it'll bite me if I don't happen to think of it then ;-) A proxy object could work by overloading `operator int&()` and `operator int const &() const`, but then again it could work by overloading `operator int() const` and `operator=(int)`.

Comment: @rhalbersma: I don't think you have to worry about constructors, since a non-const ref doesn't bind to a temporary. It's only conversion operators to reference types.

Answer (score 23):

**In my opinion, Effective STL Item 43: "Prefer algorithm calls to hand-written loops." is still a good advice.**

I usually write wrapper functions to get rid of the `begin()` / `end()` hell. If you do that, your example will look like this:

```
my_util::generate(numbers, rand);
```

I believe it beats the range based for loop both in *communicating the intent* and in readability.

---

Having said that, I must admit that in C++98 some STL algorithm calls yielded unutterable code and following "Prefer algorithm calls to hand-written loops" did not seem like a good idea. Luckily, lambdas have changed that.

Consider the following example from [Herb Sutter: Lambdas, Lambdas Everywhere](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT13).

**Task:** Find first element in v that is `> x` and `< y`.

Without lambdas:

```
auto i = find_if( v.begin(), v.end(),
bind( logical_and<bool>(),
bind(greater<int>(), _1, x),
bind(less<int>(), _1, y) ) );
```

With lambda

```
auto i=find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), [=](int i) { return i > x && i < y; } );
```

Comment: A bit orthogonal to the question. Only the first sentence addresses the question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes. The second half is explaining *why* I think Item 43 is still a good advice.

Comment: With Boost.Lambda, it's even better than with C++ lambda functions: auto i = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), _1 > x && _1 < y);

Comment: +1 for wrappers. Doing the same. Should've been in the standard from day 1 (or maybe 2... )

Comment: the second part would be almost unchanged if you replace `std::find_if` with a loop. It makes a point for lambdas but not for algorithms

Answer (score 22):

In *my* opinion, the manual loop, though might reduce verbosity, lacks readabitly:

```
for (int& x : numbers) x = rand();
```

I would not use this loop to initialize<sup>1</sup> the range defined by *numbers*, because when I look at it, it seems to me that it is *iterating over* a range of numbers, but in actuality it does not (in essence), i.e instead of *reading* from the range, it is *writing* to the range.

The intent is much clearer when you use `std::generate`.

<sup>1. *initialize* in this context means to give *meaningful* value to the elements of the container.</sup>

Comment: Isn't that just because you aren't used to range-based for loops, though? It seems fairly clear to me that this statement assigns to each element in the range. It's clear that generate does the same iff you're familiar with `std::generate`, which can be assumed of a C++ programmer (if they're not familiar, they'll look it up, same result).

Comment: @SteveJessop: This answer does not differ from the other two. It requires a bit more effort from the reader and is a bit more error prone (what if you forget a single `&` character?) The advantage of algorithms is that they show intent, while with loops you have to infer that. If there is a bug in the implementation of the loop, it is not clear whether it is a bug or it was intentional.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: this answer differs from the other two, IMO significantly. It tries to drill into the *reason* that the author finds one piece of code more clear/comprehensible than the other. The others state it without analysis. That's why I find this one interesting enough to respond to it :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: You've to look into the body of the loop to come to that conclusion that you're actually *generating* numbers, but in case of `std::generate`, just by a mere look, one can say *something* is being generated by this function; what *that something* is answered by the third argument to the function. I think this is much better.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Ok, mine is better out of laziness :) I knew procrastination had its virtue! (Just kidding, I do admit that I don't find the reasons in this answer the most compelling ones but rather what I already commented)

Comment: @Nawaz: so if the *first* thing you want your code to express, up front, is that something is being generated, then you should use `generate`. If the first thing you want your code to express is that it operates on the range `numbers`, you should use the loop?

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't think loop helps there either. Also, it is not about "first" thing or "second" thing. It is about "clearer" thing.

Comment: @Nawaz: well, first when ranked in order of clarity then. There are several facts about this code that a reader might want to know. It seems to me that your description of why you prefer `generate` is prioritizing one of those facts above the rest. I'm not convinced that priority is universal.

Comment: @SteveJessop: So it means you belong to the minority. I would write code which is clearer to the majority :P. Just last one: I didn't say anywhere that others will read the loop in the same way as I did. I said (rather *meant*) that this is one way to read the loop which is misleading to me, and because the loop body is there, different programmers will read it differently to figure out what is happening there; they might object to the usage of such loop, for different reasons, all of which could be correct according to their perception.

Comment: @Nawaz: well, you would write code that expresses one fact clearly. I might choose to write code that expresses a different fact more clearly, *if I thought that other fact was more important*. So that's why I'm interested in drilling into the reasons behind the answer :-) And agreed, it's unknown whether your or my experience matches the majority or not, that's a whole usability study. I'm willing to work with ad hoc examples. So if you (or I) fail at reading a particular bit of code, that's a data point for the duration of the conversation.

Answer (score 9):

There are some things you cannot do (simply) with range-based loops that algorithms that take iterators as input can.
For example with `std::generate`:

Fill the container up to `limit` (excluded, `limit` is a valid iterator on `numbers`) with variables from one distribution and the rest with variables from another distribution.

```
std::generate(numbers.begin(), limit, rand1);
std::generate(limit, numbers.end(), rand2);
```

Iterator-based algorithms give you a better control on the range you are operating on.

Comment: While the readability reason is a **HUGE** one to prefer algorithms, this is the only answer that shows _range-based for-loop_ is only a subset of what _algorithms_ are, and hence cannot _deprecate_ anything...

Answer (score 6):

For the particular case of `std::generate`, I agree with the previous answers on readability/intent issue. std::generate seems a more clear version to me. But I admit that this is in a way a matter of taste.

That said, I've have another reason to not throw away the std::algorithm - there are certain algorithms which are specialized for some data types.

The simplest example would be `std::fill`. The general version is implemented as a for-loop over the provided range, and this version will be used when instantiating the template. But not always. E.g. if you'll provide it a range which is a `std::vector<int>` - often it will actually call `memset` under the hood, yielding a much faster and better code.

So I'm trying to play an efficiency card here.

Your hand-written loop might be as fast as a std::algorithm version, but it can hardly be faster. And more than that, std::algorithm may be specialized for particular containers and types and it's done under the clean STL interface.

Answer (score 3):

My answer would be maybe and no. If we're talkinng about C++11, then maybe (more like no). For example `std::for_each` is really annoying to use even with lambdas:

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [&](ExactTypeOfContainedValue& x)
{
    // do stuff with x
});
```

But using range-based for is a lot better:

```
for (auto& x : c)
{
    // do stuff with x
}
```

On the other hand, if we're talking about C++1y, then I would argue that no, the algorithms will not be obsoleted by range based for. In C++ standard committee there is a study group that is working on a proposal to add ranges to C++, and also there is work being done on polymorphic lambdas. Ranges would remove the need to use pair of iterators and polymorphic lambda would let you to not specify exact argument type of lambda. This means that `std::for_each` could be used like this (don't take this as a hard fact, it's just what the dreams look like today):

```
std::for_each(c.range(), [](x)
{
    // do stuff with x
});
```

Comment: So in the latter case, the advantage of the algorithm would be that by writing `[]` with the lambda you specify zero-capture? That is, by comparison with just writing a loop body you've isolated a chunk of code from the variable lookup context that it lexically appears in. Isolation is usually helpful to the reader, less to think about while reading.

Comment: The capture is not the point. The point is that with polymorphic lambda you won't need to explicitly spell out what the type of x is.

Comment: In that case it seems to me that in this hypothetical C++1y, `for_each` is still pointless even when used with a lambda. foreach+capturing lambda is currently a verbose way of writing a range-based for loop, and it becomes slightly less verbose way but still more so than the loop. Not that I think you should have to defend `for_each`, of course, but even before seeing your answer I was thinking that if the questioner wanted to beat up algorithms, he could have picked `for_each` as the softest of all possible targets ;-)

Comment: Not going to defend `for_each`, but it has one tiny advantage over range-based for - you can make it parallel more easily just by prefixing it with parallel_ to turn it into `parallel_for_each` (if you use PPL, and assuming it's thread-safe to do so). :-D

Comment: @lego Your *"tiny"* advantage is indeed a *"big"* advantage if generalizing it up to the fact, that the `std::algorithm`s' implementation is hidden behind their interface and might be arbitrarily complex (or arbitrarily optimized).

Comment: Though indeed I agree that `std::for_each` has always been useless and doesn't get more usefull with the advent of lambdas, no matter how simple and flexible those get. While `std::generate` conveys the information of *generating values*, `std::for_each` only conveys the information of *processing each element* which I could gain equally well from a range-for.

Comment: `std::for_each` does not imply the same thing as range-for, as `for_each` is not necessarily used with `begin()` and `end()`!

Comment: By the way, your lambda-based `std::generate` is wrong. In the end you don't need a lambda for this one, anyway (other than `[]() { return rand(); }`, which would be rather ridiculous).

Comment: @MFH Neither is a range-based for, depending on its range argument.

Comment: Thanks, Christian for catching that.

Comment: @ChristianRau: It is if you're using it directly with a container, as it internally calls `begin` and `end` of the container, whereas with for_each you can specify the range...

Comment: @lego And you really changed it to this trivial lambda instead of using `std::rand` directly? Even polymorphic lambdas cannot help when driving lambda usage ad absurdum. Just drop this `std::generate` at the end, it decreases the quality of your whole answer.

Comment: @MFH: but anyone who prefers to use range-based for will have `subrange` and `iterator_range` functions in their toolkit. Range-based for necessarily iterates over the whole of the range provided to it (and the range is provided as an object on which `begin()` and `end()` can be called). `for_each` necessarily iterates over the whole of the range provided to it (and the range is provided as two iterators). I think they do convey the same information to the reader even though the range is specified differently and so one or other might be more concise in different use cases.

Comment: As an aside, range-based for loops do have an additional flexibility in that the only way to exit `for_each` early is by throwing an exception. Loops obviously you can `break`, `return` or even `goto` out of. Different people (and different contexts and uses) will offer different ideas of whether that flexibility is an advantage or a disadvantage, but anyway it doesn't apply to the example in the question.

Comment: @SteveJessop: 1. what's the benefit of range-for if I have to create a temporary just to hack a custom range into it? 2. I really wouldn't see early exit as a benefit as it breaks the basic assumption of the reader (foreach => done to EACH element) ["Principle of least astonishment" comes to mind...]

Answer (score 1):

One thing that should be noticed is that an algorithm express what is done, not how.

Range-based loop include the way things are done: start with the first, apply and go next element until the end. Even a simple algorithm could do things differently (at least some overloads for specific containers, not even thinking about the horrible vector), and at least the way it is done is not the writer business.

TO me that's much of the difference, encapsulate as much as you can, and that justifies the sentence when you can, use algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Range-based for-loop is just that. Until of course standard is changed.

Algorithm is a function. A function which puts some requirements on its parameters. The requirements are phrased in a standard to allow for example implementation that takes advantage of all available execution threads and will speed you up automatically.